# Play notification sound during call after a minute has passed

Tags: 8.1, notifications, calls

I want to ask if Windows Phone 8.1 can play a notification sound during a call after a minute has passed?

It would be very nice to hear something, just to know when the next minute starts.

Comment: Are you saying play a sound after every minute, or just the first one?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently not possible in Windows Phone. You should consider posting this feature request on the [Windows Phone Uservoice site](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions).